# imagick PHP: no such file or directory

Tags: php, imagick

i'm occour a strange error by using imagick for create some thumbnails. 
My php script receive some picture encoded in base 64, save it into a folder, then create a thumbnail for each one. 
This is my code for save picture:

```
$directory = getParentDirectory() . "/img/myfolder";

if (!is_dir($directory)) {
    $res = mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
}
$ifp = fopen($directory . "/back.jpg ", "wb");
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($back));
fclose($ifp);

//dx
$ifp = fopen($directory . "/dx.jpg ", "wb");
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($dx));
fclose($ifp);

//front
$ifp = fopen($directory . "/front.jpg ", "wb");
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($front));
fclose($ifp);

//sx
$ifp = fopen($directory . "/sx.jpg ", "wb");
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($sx));
fclose($ifp);

 createPreview($directory . "/back.jpg", $directory, "back");
createPreview($directory . "/dx.jpg", $directory, "dx");
createPreview($directory . "/sx.jpg", $directory, "sx");
createPreview($directory . "/front.jpg", $directory, "front");
```

this is crearePreview and getParentdirectyory code:

```
function createPreview($image_path, $directory, $filename) {
    $img = new Imagick($image_path);
    $img->thumbnailImage(350, 350, true);
    $img->writeImage($directory . "/" . $filename . "_prev.jpg");
}


function getParentDirectory() {

    $currentwork = getcwd();
    $parent = basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    return str_replace("/" . $parent, "", $currentwork);
}
```

but when i call createPreview i get this error:

```
11-18 10:32:28.662: I/JSON(23562): <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/old-site/sitefolder/img/myfolder/back.jpg': No such file or directory' in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/old-site/sitefolder/scripts/load_haircut_new.php:221
```

but if i check inside /img folder, all pictures (in original size) was saved, but no previews. Why imagick can't find it?

Comment: On fatal Error it prints a path, is it correct?

Comment: **/web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/old-site/sitefolder/img/myfolder/back.jpg** is no file on your server ... check it out

Comment: it's all correct, and file exists! i obtain directory folder by call getParetndirectory function!

Comment: Maybe Image magick won't create folders?

Comment: i don't need to create folder, thumbnails will be saved on the same directory of original pictures. The strange thing is that on my old hosting, that code works correctly

Comment: which is the user that the script runs on? Does she have w and x permission on the img folder ?

Comment: The code is inside the same script. Images were saved correctly in original size, but for some reason imagick could not open it